# Get Unicode string from Edit Control

Tags: c, winapi, edit

What would be the unicode version to get text length instead of `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same message.  You'll need to use CreateWindowW() or compile with UNICODE defined to get a Unicode enabled edit control.